# Cancel Button in custom default.php layout leads to form validation error

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, form, validations

I am facing a problem with my cancel button in my default.php, which is a form with some input fields aswell a save and cancel button. There are some required fields in my form. When I use the cancel button, the form validation will be activated and informs me to fill out these fields.

Could it be a result of using the default.php layout?

**05022015 - UPDATE**
The form is a front-end form and the cancel button has been done via Joomla custom JToolBar

**06022015** - Add reduced code of layout

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
                if (task == 'contact.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.getElementById('contact-form')))
        {
                        alert (task);
                        Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('contact-form'));
        } else {
                if (task != 'contact.cancel' && document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('contact-form'))) {
                        Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('contact-form'));
                } else {
                    alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED')); ?>');
                }
            }
    }               
</script>

<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_ecms&view=contact&id=' . (int) $this->form->getInput('id')); ?>" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contact-form" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="control-label"> 
                                <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('id'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('id'); ?>
                            </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="control-label"> 
                                <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('surname'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="controls">
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('surname'); ?>
                            </div>
            </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div id="toolbar-cancel" class="btn-wrapper">
                    <button class="btn btn-small" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('contact.cancel')">
                        <span class="icon-cancel"></span><?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL') ?>
                    </button>
                </div>            
        </div>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that this is a problem of Joomlas custom JToolBar, which is used here to create a Toolbar for the front end.

see last paragraph: https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

The problem is, that the work around of this article does not work!

Meanwhile I found the problem. If you have a closer look to the button code, which will be produced in the hmtl output of the site, then you will see, that the type of the button is not set. In this case, it should be 'type="button"'. If this is not set, the form validation will be triggered in any case.

A normal button integration, like suggestion of Dmitry, leads to success. Joomlas JToolbar for custom toolbars needs a correction.

Comment: With IE and Safari the form validated fields will be shown in red, but a few seconds later the cancel procedure follows. With Firefox, the validation fields will be shown in red and nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is not to use `JToolBar` at all. Do really need it? Simply make your button like this ("Cancel" button for example):

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('contact.cancel')">
    <span class="icon-cancel"></span>&#160;<?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL') ?>
</button>
```

Then in JS:

```
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task) 
{
    if (task == 'contact.cancel')
    {
        Joomla.submitform(task);
    }
}
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: I followed your recommendation! It's unbelievable, I got the same error message!!! I added the javascript now to my last post! Maybe I don't see the failure on that?!

Comment: Even when I remove the 'validation' from the form-tag and additionally comment out //JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation'), the instruction to fill out the required field comes up!!

Comment: Please show me you button code. Pay attention that it should have a `onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('company.cancel')"`. Also pay attention that you form should have `id="company-form"` if you use `document.getElementById('company-form')`. I think you mess something in the code.

Comment: here is the button code, I did it following your recommendation. The code will be triggered, because my alert statements will be shown up. Pls see my own answer below: <div id="toolbar-cancel" class="btn-wrapper">
                        <button class="btn btn-small" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('contact.save')">
                            <span class="icon-save"></span><?php echo JText::_('JSAVE') ?>
                        </button>
                    </div>

Comment: I've reduced the for to two fields, same problem. I would like to show the whole form code, whats the best way?

Comment: The best way is to update your question. Please do not write any more answers ;)

Comment: message received ;) Update has been done!

Comment: Ah it's may fault! You should not use  `document.formvalidator.isValid` in cancel... Why? Because you do not need to validate if you cancel :) I've updated my answer!

Comment: I did the change, but still the problem comes up! As i wrote, the javascript function will be initiated, also without the last change, I can see it because i implemented an alert line. So the problem must be on a different place :( (btw. Joomla Version 3.3.6)! Javascript will be initiated => submit results in form validation.

Comment: Then the problem could be in your controller which tries to validate on cancel.

Comment: I've traced with the debugger, the controller will not be reached. And it seems to me, that is clear the client side formvalidation, which breaks the continuing process. So the form won't be left by submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20885/discussion-between-dmitry-rekun-and-perino).

Comment: Iam on the way to the link that you are sent. I can see the discussion in front of me, including your last post. But it shows me no input field, instead that I have to log in. Iam logged in, I can see my Name. So sorry, it seems that i would take a few minutes. Crazy - i've also done it with a different browser, but when I go to the related chat, on the button there is a big blue field, which instructs me to log in?!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a result of the layout that you are using but a limitation of the cancel button to skip the form validation on its own.

Typically, you will need to implement something like this:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if (task == "article.cancel" || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.getElementById("item-form")))
        {
            ' . $this->form->getField('articletext')->save() . '
            Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById("item-form"));
        }
    };
');
```

This was copied from the core Joomla article `edit.php` layout (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/bd3d9cc947458437f790180fad4b817ee36e41d3/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php line 64)

The basic idea is to override the submit handler to check if it is a cancel button (with `task = VIEWNAME.cancel` OR to validate the document. This should skip the validator when you cancel and process the button as you'd expect.

You will probably need to do a few things to get this to work in your case:

1. Remove `' . $this->form->getField('articletext')->save() . '`. That is specific to that view.
2. Update `article.cancel` to be `VIEWNAME.cancel`.
3. Update the `document.getElementById(...)` to be the id for your form.

Comment: I already did your 3 steps (first recommendation i commented out). I also implemented java alert to inform me, wheter a specific position will be reached in the script. The if-clause will be reached and fullfilled, but the form validation will be still activated.

Comment: What is `task` set to when the function is called?

Comment: MyComponentName.Cancel which is in the if-clause and will be reached, following my alert statements.

Comment: Make sure that the case of the task matches exactly. If it does, the second half of that or statement will not be triggered. Also, is it making it to the submitform call before the validator runs?

Comment: When I do a alert(task) the proper taskname will be shown after clicking the cancel button. The alert statement is positioned after if (task == 'company.cancel') { alert(task);} .....now I have removed the next line Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById("item-form")); ...the validation will still triggered, although there is only the alert part in this if-else segment

Comment: Joomla.submitbutton = function(task) {  
            if (task == 'company.cancel') {   
                alert(task);
                //Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('company-form'));
            } else {
                if (task != 'company.cancel' && document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('company-form'))) {
                    Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('company-form'));
                } else {
                    alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED')); ?>');
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Always this works for me: `<script type="text/javascript">
 Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
 {
  if (task == 'company.cancel' || document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('item-form')))
  {
   Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('item-form'));
  }
 }
</script>`. Note that I add cancel button via `JToolBarHelper::cancel('company.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');` in my `display` method of `view.html.php`.

Comment: I did a custom toolbar analog https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend